# Cannot animate fire

Tags: animation

I Am trying to make an animation with one of the characters being able to use fire.
I was used i to try to animate the fire rate and did not bother to mess around with any other setting besides absolute density.
when i start the animation the fire worked until i made the fire rate go down with a keyframe but I will not respond when it goes up.
However for some reason the fire rate will not respond to the key frames.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and add more information. We have no way to look over your shoulder and see what you've done... How did you set your scene up? What are the settings for the fire? Please consider uploading the file so that others might inspect it and help you out. You can use [blendexchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload and then paste the resulting link to your post.

Comment: i have edited the post however i do not know how to upload the file

Comment: it is too big apparently

Comment: If i clear the key frames the fire works however that means i can't animate it